# Avoid Microsoft Office SDK installation as part of my app

Tags: c#, visual-studio, vsto

I have created a VSTO visual studio application in Visual Studio 2008. It's working fine and I wanted to create a installer for the same using Publish option. Now, I see that it creates the installer with Microsoft office SDK (194 MB) part of the installer. i don't want the client or my customer to install such a large component for using my relatively small app. Is there a way I can trim down the SDK to only the components I require? In other words how do I find the SDK code that I am using and only include that as part of my installer? (I do not want to include a path to sdk and client to download that file, too - so it's not just about trimming the publisher).

Thanks for any pointers.
Cheers,
Chandra

Comment: Are you sure this isn't the .NET framework getting included instead of an SDK?

Comment: @nobugz - Yep.. I am sure (unfortunately) :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Starting with Visual Studio 2010 and C# 4.0, you can avoid these large dependencies on the office SDK by taking advantage of a feature called NoPia or Interop Type Embedding.  This feature will essentially embed all COM interop types used from a given PIA into your application.  This frees you from the burden of having to deploy it as part of your application.  Here's a quick link on the subject.

- http://blogs.msdn.com/mshneer/archive/2008/10/28/advances-in-net-type-system-type-equivalence-demo.aspx